# Field Update in Process Builder

Tags: workflow, process-builder, field-update

i am exploring about new Process Builders. I learnt that we can do a field update in process builder, but I am not sure if we can do it in the same way as we do it in workflow field update. I mean, can we update the value of the field based on a formula in process builder?

In the attached screen shot, I have the something called Operator drop down which I need to specify when building it. What if my formula return something called 'Yes' and I would like to assign stage field value as Closed Won if it is 'Yes'. What should I set in Operator then? In workflow field update I just need to specify the formula ex - if( date>'mm/dd/yy' ,' Closed won','Open'). How can I achieve that in process builder?

2 part) Can workflow field update use formula field in its formula condition but process builder can not use a formula field in Formula?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Operator, you should choose **Equals**.  And the type you correctly chose as **Formula**.  When you chose the formula, below it, you need to enter your formula and click **Use this formula**.

You formula will be something like this (modify according to your needs). This is similar to how you write other formulae.)

```
if( opp.Close_Date__c>'mm/dd/yy','Closed won','Open')
```

The above formula output is Closed Won, that will be set as your Stage!  You can further add more complex formula to set whatever stage you want as.